# JMeter web driver error using chrome version 112

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, jmeter-plugins

```
2023-04-12 21:40:45,183 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2023-04-12 21:40:45,183 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-04-12 21:40:45,185 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2023-04-12 21:40:45,205 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2023-04-12 21:40:45,205 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2023-04-12 21:40:45,205 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2023-04-12 21:40:45,205 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1           delayedStart=false
2023-04-12 21:40:45,266 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-04-12 21:40:45,266 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-04-12 21:40:45,276 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2023-04-12 21:40:45,912 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2023-04-12 21:40:46,436 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isBlank()Z
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.combineCustomCapabilities(WebDriverConfig.java:443) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.createChromeOptions(WebDriverConfig.java:299) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:27) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:14) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:221) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:152) ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-4.8.3.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:797) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) ~[jorphan.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:765) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:753) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:264) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_361]
2023-04-12 21:40:46,438 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-04-12 21:40:46,438 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

I'm using chrome Version 112.0.5615.50 (Official Build) (64-bit) and WebDriver
can anyone help please.

Already tried this `remote-allow-origins=*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per stacktrace:

1. The plugin is using [String.isBlank()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) function as the plugin developers/maintainers don't worry about backward and JMeter compatibility
2. The function is available since [Java 11](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/11/)

   [image]
3. You're using Java 8 which doesn't have this String.isBlank() function

The options are in:

1. Upgrade to Java 11 or higher (anyway [it's recommended to use latest JMeter and Java when possible](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use))
2. Downgrade WebDriver Sampler plugin to version prior 4.8.3 using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

   [image]

Comment: Thank you works fine on my end